# How to run a perl file in a terminal pipeline

Tags: perl, terminal

Probably a very simple question:
I have a perl file `sed.perl` that takes as an input a string, makes some substitutions there and prints it on the standard output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use feature 'say';
#use Cwd;

my ($text) = @ARGV; 

$text =~ s/\.\)\n/'\.'\)\n/;

print $text;
```

I want to feed the script with a string output from a terminal pipeline. Let's say in this way:

```
cat input.txt | perl sed.perl
```

but this doesn't work: `Use of uninitialized value $text in substitution (s///) at`

Using a score symbol doesn't works either:

```
cat input.txt | perl sed.perl -
```

Answer (score 2):

`@ARGV` doesn't do what you think it does. It's literally the arguments passed to perl.

E.g. :

```
myscript.pl some arg
```

`@ARGV` will host `'some', 'arg'`.

What you want is the `STDIN` file handle.

e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <STDIN> ) {
    s/something/somethingelse/g; 
    print;
}
```

Now what this is doing is reading `STDIN` line by line. Your pattern includes `\n`.  Do you actually need it? It looks like you're 'just' using it as a line anchor, and so you could use:

```
s/\.\)$/'\.'\)/g;
```

`$` is the regex for "end of line" - see [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more.

However, as noted in the comments by [reinierpost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17945/reinierpost) - there's another thing that's probably useful to know - perl has the "diamond operator" `<>` which does two things:

- If filenames are specified to the script, opens them and reads from them.
- If no arguments specified, reads `STDIN`.

So you could do:

```
while ( <> ) {
    s/something/somethingelse/g; 
    print;
}
```

And then your script can either be invoked by:

```
cat input.txt | ./yourscript.pl
```

Or:

```
./yourscript.pl input.txt
```

And you'll have the same result.

Comment: You might add that it's better style to use `<>` rather than `<STDIN>`: with `<>` the user of the script can always optionally pass in as arguments the names of files to take the input from, which is a common and useful convention for Unix utilities to follow.

Comment: `\n` will match (unless you use -l with -n or -p)

Comment: OK, amended. Wasn't sure which scenarios it had problems with.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read the text as if it were an argument, when in fact with a pipeline the information from `input.txt` will be something you read from `stdin`.  With a pipeline `stdout` from the left process is connected to `stdin` of the right process.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `@ARGV` contains arguments to your script, and you'll want to use `STDIN` instead.

The shortest solution seems to be:

```
#/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

while(<>) {
    print s/\.\)$/'.')/r;
}
```

Note that you could also achieve the results of your example using a one-liner as follows:

```
cat input.txt | perl -pe 's/your/substitution/'
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need a `g` on the end of the pattern?

Comment: no, since the OP wants to match at the end of the line, g is not needed or wanted

Comment: btw, `for(<>)` loads the _whole_ file in memory, while `while(<>)` doesn't.